# Multiple Join in codeigniter don't wortk

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

Can you help me with fixing my bug?

I tried to join three tables: Users, crush, and discrush.

But no result is found with this code.

**Database:**

- Users: id, and stuff
- Crush: id, user_id, user_id_to
- Discrush: id, user_id, user_id_to

**Query:**

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `users`
  RIGHT JOIN `discrush` ON `users`.`id` = `discrush`.`user_id_to`
  RIGHT JOIN `crush` ON `users`.`id` = `discrush`.`user_id_to`
WHERE
  `users`.`sexe` = 'female'
  AND `users`.`valid_admin` = '1'
  AND `users`.`id` NOT IN('81')
  AND `crush`.`user_id_to` is NULL
  OR `users`.`sexe` = 'female'
  AND `users`.`valid_admin` = '1'
  AND `users`.`id` NOT IN('81')
  AND `discrush`.`user_id_to` is NULL
ORDER BY
  RAND()
```

**Model:**

```
function GetUserForCrushRoom($my_user_id, $sexe)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->join('discrush', 'users.id = discrush.user_id_to', 'right');
    $this->db->join('crush', 'users.id = discrush.user_id_to', 'right');

    $this->db->where('users.sexe =', $sexe);
    $this->db->where('users.valid_admin =', '1');
    $this->db->where_not_in('users.id', $my_user_id);
    $this->db->where('crush.user_id_to is NULL');

    $this->db->or_where('users.sexe =', $sexe);
    $this->db->where('users.valid_admin =', '1');
    $this->db->where_not_in('users.id', $my_user_id);
    $this->db->where('discrush.user_id_to is NULL');
    $this->db->order_by('users.id', 'RANDOM');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();

}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function crush_room()
{
    $my_user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    if($my_user_id != '')
    {
        $data['my_user_id'] = $my_user_id;
        $my_user = $this->home->get_user($my_user_id);

            $sexe = $my_user->sexe;

            if($my_user->sexe == 'male')
            {
                $sexe = 'female';
            }else{
                $sexe = 'male';
            }

            $data['user'] = $this->home->GetUserForCrushRoom($my_user_id, $sexe);

            if($data['user']){
                $data['user_crush'] = $this->home->CheckCrush($my_user_id, $data['user']->id);
                $data['user_block'] = $this->home->CheckBlockUser($my_user_id, $data['user']->id);
            }

            $data['users'] = $this->home->get_all_user_crush($my_user_id);

            $this->load->view('crush_room', $data);
    }
    else{
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: `echo $this->db->get_compiled_select()` to see the query

Comment: Query add on the original post

Comment: can you let us know what is the result you are expecting, so that we can help you out?

Comment: No result my friend

Answer (score 1):

I got the FIX !

Replace the query by this ...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users U WHERE U.sexe = ? AND U.valid_admin = '1' AND U.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id_to FROM discrush UNION SELECT user_id_to FROM crush)";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($sexe));

        return $query->row();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try joining crush with users.

RIGHT JOIN `crush` ON `users`.`id` = `crush`.`user_id_to`

Comment: Try expanding your answer with comments about your code, what does it do, why does it work. why the current solution is not working,

Comment: What I feel is, He is joining the crush table but referring the users and discrush table only. This could be a problem.

Comment: it's for create a website for meet other people like tinder

Comment: Can you please mention the result set you are expecting? Also please check your AND clauses, might be there are no rows matching your where and AND clauses.